# alert div id when click on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created new website and on it I want when I click on one div jquery show me div ID and I user this command and I can give div ID

```
var name = $(this).attr("id");
```

and when I want to give div's child I use this Command

```
var name =  $(this).children(".select").attr("name");
```

now I have 3 divs like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHKyw.png)

and when I click on div 3 Jquery give me div2 with this command

```
var name =  $(this).children(".select").attr("name");
```

how can I get div's ID when click on it?

example click on div 1 show me div 1 or when I click on div 2 show me div 2
and when I click on div 3 show me div 3

Thanks

Comment: Show your html and javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code was correct, you don't need to find `children`...

```
$("div").click( function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log( name );
});
```

If you have trouble with multiple events, you can stop propagating the click event with `.stopPropagation()` like so:

```
$("div").click( function( e ){
    var name = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log( name );
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/tg4rmkk9/

Answer (score 0):

You've already solved the main part of the problem:

`var name = $(this).attr("id");`

This will get you the ID of the Div.

To alert it you can then do `alert(name);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of what I think you're going for :

```js
$('[id^=div]').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    Click me
</div>
<div id="div2">
    Click me too
</div>
<div id="div3">
    Click me three
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsjjwwpw/))